# Morphing with Velocity.js doesnt work

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, morphing

Hej,

i have this plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/bKzi6rU3lIXT4Nz2wkR8?p=info

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilovi/main.css">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="avengers"></div>
</body>
<script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function fetchXML(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(evt) {
      //Do not explicitly handle errors, those should be
      //visible via console output in the browser.
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        callback(xhr.responseXML);
      }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  };

  /*var list = ["test3.svg","test.2svg"];*/
  //fetch the document
  fetchXML("test3.svg", function(newSVGDoc) {
    //import it into the current DOM
    var n = document.importNode(newSVGDoc.documentElement, true);
    document.getElementById("avengers").appendChild(n);

    var ironman = document.getElementsByTagName("polygon");

    var ironmanlist = Array.prototype.slice.call(ironman);
    /*alert(ironmanlist.length);*/
    ironmanlist.forEach(function(elem, i) {
      /*for (var index = 0; index < elem.points.length; ++index){
                    //2.test case morphing each point (not working)//
                    console.log(elem.points[index]);
                    $.Velocity(elem.points[index],{x:100,y:100},{duration:Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000}, "ease-in-out");
                    //3.test case morphing each point in another way (not working)//
                    /*$(elem.points[index])
                        .velocity({x:100,y:100},{duration:Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000}, "ease-in-out");
                    console.log(elem.points[index]);
                }*/
      //1. working test case (translation)//
      console.log(elem.points[0].x);
      $.Velocity(elem, {
        translateX: -300
      }, {
        duration: Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000
      }, "ease-in-out");
      //$.Velocity(elem,{rotateZ:"45deg"},{duration:Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000}, "ease-in-out");
      console.log(elem.points[0].x);
      //End of 1. working test case//
    });
    console.log(ironmanlist);


  });
</script>

</html>
```

With my code, and some examples. What I want to do is morph each polygon from one SVG image, into another polygon from another SVG image. The translation works, but I'm not sure how to do a morph.
Can anyone help, or check the code and tell me what I am doing wrong?
There are a lot of polygons, and I need it to be fast so i went with velocity.js for this.

I was also thinking of maybe moving it all to three.js, and maybe convert it to a format that would be best to use with three.js. But if it is a possibilty to use it as svg and keep a great performance i would do so.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, velocity.js doesn't support this as (taken from [their website](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#svg)):

> In general, Velocity can animate any property that takes a single numeric value.

As SVG paths usually (always?) consist of multiple values, morphing is way beyond their current scope.

However, I can highly recommend [Snap](http://snapsvg.io/) for morphing SVG paths.